# Passing select value to another select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS as my CSS framework and I also wasted 1 hour searching for the answers in google/stackoverflow etc.. but I can't seem to find the answer to solve this problem. So, what I am doing is I'm trying to pass the value of Select 1 to Select 2. Here is my code below

Select 1:

```
<select id="Accounts">
  <option value="">Choose Account to edit</option>
     <?php
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM personnel_list WHERE status = ?";
        $result = $this->db->query($query, array("Active"))->result_array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
           extract($row);
           echo "<option value=\"$id-$name-$position-$status\">$name</option>";
        }
   ?>
</select>
```

Select 2:

```
<select id="editPosition">
    <option value="">Choose Position</option>
        <?php
            $Position = array("Manager", "Supervisor", "Assistant Manager", "Assistant Supervisor")
            for ($x=0; $x < count($Position); $x++) { 
                echo "<option value=\"$Position[$x]\">$Position[$x]</option>";
            }
        ?>
</select>
<label for="editPosition">Position:</label>
```

JS:

```
$("#Accounts").change(function(){
var accval  = $(this).val().split("-");
var id      = accval[0];
var name    = accval[1];
var post    = accval[2];
var status  = accval[3];

$("#editPosition").val(post);
})
```

Other JS that I have tried is:

```
$("#editPosition option[value='"+post+"']").prop("selected", true);
```

Rendered Select 1:

```
<select id="Accounts">
<option value="">Choose Account to edit</option>
<option value="1-John-Manager-Active">John</option><option value="2-Mark-Assistant Manager-Active">Mark</option>
</select>
```

Rendered Select 2:

```
<select id="editPosition">
<option value="">Choose Position</option>
<option value="Manager">Manager</option>
<option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
<option value="Assistant Manager">Assistant Manager</option>
<option value="Assistant Supervisor">Assistant Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance for those who will answer and help me!

Comment: show the render html.

Comment: @GentiSaliu Hello what do you mean? The variables in the value attribute are not empty. I checked them by putting them on alert() 1 by 1. It seems that the problem is not there but in my js code.

Comment: @BenG updated, check pls

Comment: @Akio Your code is fine and works, see https://jsfiddle.net/9w0t1yxw/1/ You must be getting JavaScript errors somewhere else (usually before the JS code you posted here gets executed).

Comment: show the html code, not an image. we need to see the generated html. right click on the page and 'view page source'.

Comment: True, obviously the `editPosition` values are **not** post IDs from first select, but positions. Please post the rendered HTML and you can remove PHP part from the question, it is not relevant at all.

Comment: I have posted the rendered HTML for Select 1 and select 2 @BenG

Comment: @GentiSaliu I can't seem to find an error on my console :/

Comment: Even with your HTML code it is still working: https://jsfiddle.net/9w0t1yxw/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation to listen for changes on the `Accounts` select instead:

```
$("#Accounts").on("change", function(){
    var accval  = $(this).val().split("-");
    var id      = accval[0];
    var name    = accval[1];
    var post    = accval[2];
    var status  = accval[3];

    $("#editPosition").val(post);
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9w0t1yxw/13/) for a working example.

Materialize CSS does a lot of modifications to the DOM when it renders its components, making straightforward JavaScript operations on UI elements from your part break at times.

Comment: Oml. This solved my problem! Tysm! I also realized the problem is within materialize but I can't seem to find the answer. Thank you again for helping me! Kudos!!

Comment: Actually, there is no need to reinitialize the the select if you use event delegation. WIll update my answer in a moment.